# Função para criar gráficos por coluna

Tags: r, funções, gráfico, princípios-de-programação

Estou utilizando esse código para plotar pirâmides etárias:

```
p_etarias <- read.csv(file "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\DemandasCEInfo\\20200327_CNSAÚDE\\Piramides\\R\\p_etarias.csv", sep = ";",dec = ",", header = TRUE)

summary(p_etarias)

xy.pop<-c(p_etarias[1:16,1])
xx.pop<-c(p_etarias[17:32,1])
agelabels<-c("0-4","5-9","10-14","15-19","20-24","25-29","30-34",
             "35-39","40-44","45-49","50-54","55-59","60-64","65-69","70-74",
             "75+")
mcol<-color.id('#5882FA')
fcol<-color.id('#FE2E2E')

piramide1 <- par(mar=pyramid.plot(xy.pop,xx.pop,labels=agelabels,
                 main=" Pirâmide Etária de Anhanguera",lxcol=mcol,rxcol=fcol,
                 gap=1,show.values=FALSE, top.labels = c("Masc", "Idade", "Fem"),
                 ndig = 5, ))
```

O que eu quero fazer é criar uma função que rode esse código para todas as colunas do meu banco de dados. Eu gostaria de saber se é possível eu programar para esse código rodar em todas as colunas alterando apenas o nome que está ali no argumento main da função pyramid_plot, plotando as pirâmides e salvando-as. Ou terei de alterar manualmente o número da coluna quando defino os parametrôs xy.pop e xx.pop? São 96 distritos administrativos e quero fazer uma pirâmide etária para todos eles.

Comment: Olá Lucca, bem vindo ao SO em português. Consulte a Central de Ajuda para ver como fazer boas perguntas, em especial como providenciar um exemplo mínimo verificável.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para o que pretende precisa 1) usar o nome da coluna (ou usando diretamente o nome ou obtendo-o pelo número) e 2) armazenar o nome da coluna em um objeto. Pode então usar um *loop* (dentro ou fora da função, de acordo com a conveniência) para percorrer todas as colunas.

Como não postou uma amostra dos seus dados nem o código (ou pacote) da função `pyramid.plot`, estou criando um exemplo genérico, com dados aleatórios e uma função que gera e salva em um arquivo um gráfico XY de cada coluna.

```
p_etarias <- data.frame(a = rnorm(32, 10),
                        b = rnorm(32, 8),
                        c = rnorm(32, 12))

plotacols_xy <- function(df) {
  for (col in colnames(df)) {
    xy.pop <- df[1:16, col]
    xx.pop <- df[17:32, col]
    png(paste0('XYplot_', col, '.png'))
      plot(x = xx.pop, y = xy.pop, main = paste('Gráfico XY da coluna', col))
    dev.off()
  }
}

plotacols_xy(p_etarias)
```